# Monitor that lambda executes in NewRelic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'm trying to monitor if my Lambda has been executed within the last 25 hours within New Relic. I want to alert if it hasn't.

I have the following NRQL which gives me the graph I want to see:

`` SELECT sum(`provider.invocations.Sum`) FROM ServerlessSample WHERE provider.resource = 'my_lambda_name' ``

I then just want to say that if it dips below 1 for 1500 minutes (25 hours) then alert, but NR only allows me to set an alarm for 120 minutes. Any tips on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, as I have seen in New Relic discussion page, or Explorers Hub, there might be solution for your task.

Can you please review this link:

- https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-extending-the-functionality-of-nrql-alert-conditions-beyond-a-single-minute/75441

> If you think about this for a moment, you might see how NRQL queries using `percentile` or `stddev` are a lot less useful than they seem, when used in an alert condition. After all, if you calculate the standard deviation over an hour (or 24 hours), that can be meaningful. But `stddev(duration)`, or `percentile(duration,95)` calculated over only 60 seconds is less meaningful.

I think that limit is 24 hours but I haven't test it yet.
Hope this will help you, I will try to give it a go as well to see will this work.

Comment: That's so dirty! I love it though and it does solve the problem. I've also just asked NR to support it natively.